# How to restore Sublime 3 to the restore single-window mode?

Tags: sublimetext3

I am using Sublime 3 but I am a newbie. I was trying to define some preferences, like the font size. However, I messed up things and I am not being able to restore.

Currently, I have this two windows "dashboard":

[image]

How can I restore it to the default one-window view?

I tried to look for things over the preference menu, but checking/unchecking all the available options did not help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Use `View > Layout > Single` from the menu to get back to a single column view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you added an extra column. Try going to View, then setting Layout to Single or use the keyboard shortcut: `Shift+Alt+1`.

Comment: For the sake of completeness only, the menu options for this are the same under MacOS as under Windows/Linux but the key binding is `Command+Alt+1` instead of `Shift+Alt+1` there.

Answer (score 3):

If you used File/Split View, setting single column mode won't work.  In this case I found you can just click on another tab and the split will go away.  Not at all intuitive.