# How to get rid of multiple panes on Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text 3 and somehow 2 additional panes popped up. I might have pressed some keys but I don't know which. I couldn't any help online and I've even tried re-installing sublime text 3. Nothing works.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restore Sublime 3 to the restore single-window mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356280/how-to-restore-sublime-3-to-the-restore-single-window-mode)

Comment: Thanks now the problem is solved.

Answer (score 3):

I think you mistakenly adjusted the layout. It can sometimes be in the row (in your case), grid or column.

And for others who might run into this problem later on, here is the solution:

To fix this simply open your Sublime Text 3, go to the menu bar click **"View"** then **"Layout"** and click **"Single"** to have your default view back.

Note: This solution is for Sublime Text 3 (ST3).